# PHP: Advanced ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a real estate website and I wanted to have the listings sorted by the last update and completeness of the listing. So I have been trying to figure out how to sort by a field in mysql (completion_score) in combination with the most recently updated listing. The completion score would be on a 100 point scale with 0 being bad and 100 being perfectly complete. I will have the completion score calculated when the listing is added and updated and saved in the mysql database. I am guessing that I will have to somehow combine the date and the completion_score to make a total, but I am unsure how to do this in one SELECT.

Currently I am using this (which obviously doesn't account for completion score):

```
ORDER BY ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_featured DESC, ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated DESC
```

I was thinking that if it was completed in the last week I would add 30 points to the completion score, if it was completed in the last month I would add 20 points to the completion score, and if it was completed in the last three months I would add 10 points to the completion score. I could then order it by this updated completion score. The problem is how do I have it change each day to adjust the score.

Taking Mark's advice I put in the following code:

```
ORDER BY $wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_score' + if($wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated' > NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK,30,if($wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated' > NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH,20,if($wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated' > NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTHS,10,0)))' DESC';
```

---

I then received the following Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/...

Comment: Is one more important than the other? Or are you trying to make them both of equal importance?

Comment: I'd suggest removing the PHP and wordpress tags because they're not relevant to the answer if you want to use mysql to do the sorting.

Comment: I am trying to have a weighted score where they are somewhat equal, but definitely not the traditional ORDER BY last_update, completion_score. If it was updated in the last week it would have an increase of 30 points, 1 month 20 points, and 3 months 10 points. So, essentially if the listing is one hundred percent complete and it was updated 1.5 months ago it would have score of 110.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like:

```
order by completeion_score - (to_days(now()) - to_days(completion_date))/3
```

or some similar function of the number of days that have passed since completion.

**UPDATE**

The code I've given you above is SQL only, there is no php involved, therefore everything should be within quotes except for the `$wpdb->prefix` parts. (This goes for @Mark's answer as well as most of the others that give you code, I'd imagine.)

to add your prefixes, your code should look something like this:

```
"ORDER BY ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_score - (to_days(now()) - to_days(".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated))/3"
```

Comment: I received the following: Fatal error: Call to undefined function to_days() in /home... Here is my code: ORDER BY $wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_score' - (to_days(now()) - to_days($wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated'))/3;

Answer (score 3):

Your idea sounds good. Why not run with it?

```
ORDER BY completion_score + IF(date > NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK,30,IF(date > NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH,20,IF(date > NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTHS,10,0))) DESC
```

Something to that effect anyway.

Comment: This was more along the lines of what I was thinking. I will have to mess around with this tomorrow. Thank You!

Comment: I would but I don't have enough reputation. I will as soon as i have the 15 points required. I just found this website and it is awesome!!

Comment: @ChrisAllington: oh..didnt know there was min rep for voting...that's sad. haha... welcome to S.O.!! it is indeed a wonderful site.

Comment: I put in the following code: $wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_score' + if($wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated' > NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK,30,if($wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated' > NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH,20,if($wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated' > NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTHS,10,0)))' DESC'; ---------- I then received the following Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/...

Comment: @Chris, The `IF` in the answer is a SQL function, not a php statement, so it should be inside quotes.

Comment: @jswolf19 I tried it with 'IF' and it gave me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in /home/...

Comment: Here is the code so far: ORDER BY $wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_score' + 'IF'($wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated' > NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK,30,'IF'($wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated' > NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH,20,'IF'($wpdb->prefix.'fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated' > NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTHS,10,0)))' DESC';

Comment: @ChrisAllington:  First, `.` is the concatentation operator, second, you're missing one between `'IF'` and `($wpdb...`. Just keep debugging it until the syntax errors go away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide exactly how you want the sorting to work, but if you want you can do `ORDER BY completion_date DESC, completion_score DESC`, which will give you the most recent days first, within equal dates they'll be ordered by score.

Comment: I have thought about this method. The problem would be if someone put in a really incomplete listing on Monday it would show up higher than someone who filled out a listing 100% on Tuesday. I want to give people listings that are both fresh and complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can think it in reverse way, so that you don't have to update your old entries. Consider the current week 0, then next week 10, next 20 and so on. I think you don't need the `QUERY` for this :)